# How to append list with a for loop?

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm having issues writing a function that outputs a list by applying a for-loop over another list.
I want to divide each value by the list's maximum and then multiply by 100.

Here is what I tried and my data:

```
bn<- function(x)
{result<- list()
 p<- max(x)
for (i in 1:NROW(x))
{c <- x[i]/p*100
result[[i]] <- c
}}
```

where x is list input.

```
df<-structure(list(tt = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), pp = c(34, 35, 77, 23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Outside the function this approach works but for some reason I can't make it work here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change on your function:

```
#Function
bn<- function(x)
{
  result<- list()
  p<- max(x)
  for (i in 1:NROW(x))
  {
    c <- x[i]/p*100
    result[[i]] <- c
  }
  return(result)
}
#Apply
bn(df$pp)
```

Output:

```
bn(df$pp)
[[1]]
[1] 44.15584

[[2]]
[1] 45.45455

[[3]]
[1] 100

[[4]]
[1] 29.87013
```

Comment: In fact, this was the issue. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot.